# Generics around Entityframework DbContext causes performance degradation?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, generics, dbcontext

I wrote a simple import/export application that transforms data from source->destination using EntityFramework and AutoMapper. It basically:

1. **selects** `batchSize` of records from the source table
2. '**maps**' data from source->destination entity
3. **add** new destination entities to destination table and **saves** context

I move around *500k records in under 5 minutes*. After I *refactored* the code *using generics* the performance *drops drastically to 250 records in 5 minutes.*

**Are my delegates that return `DbSet<T>` properties on the `DbContext` causing these problems? Or is something else going on?**

## Fast non-generic code:

```
public class Importer
{        
    public void ImportAddress()
    {
        const int batchSize = 50;
        int done = 0;
        var src = new SourceDbContext();

        var count = src.Addresses.Count();

        while (done < count)
        {
            using (var dest = new DestinationDbContext())
            {
                var list = src.Addresses.OrderBy(x => x.AddressId).Skip(done).Take(batchSize).ToList();
                list.ForEach(x => dest.Address.Add(Mapper.Map<Addresses, Address>(x)));

                done += batchSize;

                dest.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        src.Dispose();
    }
}
```

## (Very) slow generic code:

```
public class Importer<TSourceContext, TDestinationContext>
    where TSourceContext : DbContext
    where TDestinationContext : DbContext
{
    public void Import<TSourceEntity, TSourceOrder, TDestinationEntity>(Func<TSourceContext, DbSet<TSourceEntity>> getSourceSet, Func<TDestinationContext, DbSet<TDestinationEntity>> getDestinationSet, Func<TSourceEntity, TSourceOrder> getOrderBy) 
        where TSourceEntity : class
        where TDestinationEntity : class
    {
        const int batchSize = 50;
        int done = 0;
        var ctx = Activator.CreateInstance<TSourceContext>();
        //Does this getSourceSet delegate cause problems perhaps?

        //Added this
        var set = getSourceSet(ctx);

        var count = set.Count(); 

        while (done < count)
        {
            using (var dctx = Activator.CreateInstance<TDestinationContext>())
            {
                var list = set.OrderBy(getOrderBy).Skip(done).Take(batchSize).ToList(); 
                //Or is the db-side paging mechanism broken by the getSourceSet delegate?
                //Added this
                var destSet = getDestinationSet(dctx);
                list.ForEach(x => destSet.Add(Mapper.Map<TSourceEntity, TDestinationEntity>(x)));

                done += batchSize;
                dctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        ctx.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new destination instance in every iteration of the while block? You can move that using outside of the while statement.

Comment: Profile the app and know for sure! If you have no profiler at hand, pause the debugger 10 times.

Comment: You ask questions in the comment that can easily be verified by time tracing (StopWatch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is invocation of the `Func` delegates you're doing a lot. Cache the resulting values in variables and it'll be fine.

Comment: I changed the generic code (see //Added this) to use variables for `Func<>` results but it's still slow...

Comment: It's still inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Correct, it needs to create a new context after each batch because of caching.. Otherwise the object becomes way to big.

Comment: You can remove processed objects from context using `Detach` method.